# Problem to install latest version of shellcheck from tar.xz

Tags: software-installation, tar, path, ln

I have been downloading the latest version of [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and tried to install it on my System taking the following steps:

I downloded shellcheck-latest.linux.x86_64.tar.xz
then I run as root:

```
# extracting the tar
tar --directory=/opt -xvf shellcheck-latest.linux.x86_64.tar.xz

# added the directory to path
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/shellcheck/bin

# created a symlink:
cd /usr/bin
ln -s /opt/shellcheck shellsheck
```

if I try to run the program I always get the following error (translated from german):

> bash: /usr/bin/shellcheck: Can not run binary file: wrong format.

In the README it says:

> This is a precompiled ShellCheck binary.

so I thought I would run fine with this steps.

Here are some of my system informations:

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.11.0-1-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
```

Comment: Is: `ln -s /opt/shellcheck shellsheck` an innocent typo at the end?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, oh thanks. Though this was not the problem. I used autocomplete and so I invoked the binary, but without realizing this typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the 32-bit version of Spellcheck. Your kernel is not the x86_64 64-bit kernel.

Comment: ok there we go, thanks. I thought ...x86_64 was working for x86.

Comment: Yeah, naming convention is a little ambigous.

Comment: importunately I do not find a pre-compiled version for 32bit. So I'll stick with the LTS version from the debian repository. I just found a way of ignoring the errors I wanted to get rid of with the newest version. Ohh btw. the application is called "ShellCheck" not "SpellCheck"

Comment: What about downloading the source and compiling it yourself?

Comment: I just never did it. If I can spend a little more time for that this is definitely an option. I thought this one was really easy but honestly I misinterpreted x86_64 as working for both and was already wondering the tar was only containing one binary.